# How to get the baselayer selected in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

How to get the baselayer selected in leaflet?

[image: Screenshot 1]

Answer (score 13):

Listen for the `baselayerchange` event on your mapinstance:

> Fired when the base layer is changed through the layer control.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-baselayerchange

```
map.on('baselayerchange', function (e) {
    console.log(e.layer);
});
```